# How can I fix network printer always being offline in Windows 10 when Configure port is not supported?

Tags: windows-10, network-printer

Windows 10 keeps thinking my Samsung ML-2950 printer is offline, and to fix it I have to remove it then re-add it in Windows settings. Not too onerous for me, but it's a family PC, and my mother can't manage that, and she always wants everything printed.

The printer supports HTTP and IPP, but not SMB AFAICT. I've configured my router to allocate it a static IP address, because I think that's one of the issues which can cause this problem, but that alone isn't enough to fix it. If I search for a solution, the answers mostly say I need to navigate to the dialog where there's a Ports tab with a Configure port... button, click that and disable SNMP. The trouble is, the checked port for this printer is a WSD port, and clicking the Configure button just brings up an error: "Operation not supported". There are no TCP/IP ports in the list, just WSD and the usual ones for file, USB etc.

Comment: Errant printers are often problematic. Uninstall the printer, then remove the driver as well (normally Devices and Printers).  Restart and then use Devices and Printers, Add Printer and add the printer using Windows on board drivers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, opening the print queue for the relevant printer, then in the 'printer' menu select  'use printer offline' - close the menu, then open it again and deselect 'use printer offline'. Then reopen the print dialog for whatever program you want to print from and hopefully the printer will no show as being online. (this presupposes you've checked it's turned on and connected to the network ;-) )